# Interpretation of weak equality

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

If we assume that $f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions such that $f_{|\gamma}=g_{|\gamma}$ where $\gamma$ is the interface between two triangles $K1$ and $K2$ (we are in the context of finite elements), we can write obviously:

$f_{|\gamma}=g_{|\gamma}$ in the space $C^{0}(\gamma)$. (1)

Now, assume I do not have the equality above, but the following equality:

$\int_\gamma f_{|\gamma}\varphi_{\sigma}=\int_\gamma g_{|\gamma}\varphi_{\sigma}$. (2)

for all $\sigma$ where $\varphi_\sigma$ is the Lagrange basis function associated to the degree of freedom $\sigma$ defined for the finite element $(\gamma,P^k,\Sigma_\gamma)$ (again, I am using the standard notations of the finite element methods).

I think I can say that:

(2) is a weaker statement than (1),

(2) is true for all polynomials $p$ of $P^k(\gamma)$ by linearity:
$\int_\gamma fp=\int_\gamma gp$.

How can I interpret the equality (2) ?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. In FEM you have a weak form of the original equation which has a space of solution candidates $U$ and a space of test functions $V$. You identify a subspace of FEM solution candidates $U_h$ and a subspace of FEM test functions $V_h$. You write down the weak equation in terms of just the test functions in $V_h$ and you seek a solution to it drawn from $U_h$.

Comment: Then the equations holding for the test functions in $V_h$, under typical choices of $V_h$, mean that the equation holds "on average" on each element, where the weight in the average depends on the test functions used.

Comment: I think your question might not be so much about FEM as it is about the original weak form of the equation. For example, how can I understand the significance of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} fv$ for a single $v$? Is that correct?

Comment: I think I do not understand your comment. I would need to deduce from (2) an equality like (1), I mean I would need to find in what spaces f=g from (2). I think something smaller than L2, but of course bigger than C0. The problem comes from a finite element problem, but yes it is just a matter of interpreting the significance of (2).

Comment: Oh, you're trying to infer f=g from just (2)? That's more or less a linear algebra question: you have some number $n$ of linearly independent test functions, so typically if you choose a space of solution candidates of dimension at most $n$, (2) (with a quantifier over all your test functions) will imply (1). Conversely, typically (2) will not imply (1) if your space of solution candidates has dimension larger than $n$.

Comment: I have rewritten the question. The problem is: I loose continuity of f and g at the interface $\gamma$, so I do not have (1) any more, but a weaker statement: (2). What can I say about f and g ? In what space are they equal ?

Comment: What I said seems to still apply even though you have changed the problem to involving $\gamma$ instead. They are only guaranteed to be equal if the space they live in is low dimensional.

Comment: Ok. So if $f$ and $g$ are in a space of dimension higher than the space of the test functions p, what can be said about $f$ and $g$ ? They are not required to coincide on $\gamma$ (as they do not necessarily verify (1)), so what is the meaning of (2) ?

Comment: Is the answer evident or to the contrary is the meaning of (2) difficult to describe ?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to describe it other than in terms of measuring the deviation between $f$ and $g$ averaged against a weight defined by $\varphi$, as I already said. That, and the fact that they will actually agree in the strong sense if the equality holds for a large enough set of $\varphi$ and enough regularity on $f,g$ is assumed. But in FEM you don't have that large set of $\varphi$.